# Simple regex - (Group matching in C++)

Tags: c++, regex

I have a file with the following text format:

```
Blah blah Blahhh<TAB SPACE -(/t character)>1234<TAB SPACE -(/t character)>some other crap blah
```

The text may look like:

```
Saturday Evening    1234    Beautiful
```

I am using the `<regex>` library, and I want to use capture groups to only capture the "1234".

I tried:

```cpp
"\\t(\\d+)\\t"
```

But when I print the results, it shows the "\t" characters along with the numbers. Any ideas?

Comment: Test regexe online: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\b\d+\b`  to include word boundaries.That would ignore the tabs or whitespaces that are matching in your current regex.

http://regexr.com?32a07

Or if you want to match with tabs , use assertions, they will match the tabs, but not capture them :

```
(?<=\t)\d+(?=\t)
```

Answer (score 0):

A few details would be useful, like the code you use to do the search and extract the results, but my guess is that you're looking at the wrong match_result index: you should be looking at element 1. See match_results' [operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results/operator_at)